# android background service that triggers manual events

Tags: android, keyboard, keyboard-events, usb-otg

I recently discovered that I could connect my wireless keyboard and mouse with my phone using an OTG adapter. My phone now has an always available, physical keyboard as well as a cursor.

I was curious if I could reroute the keyboard input to preform different manual touch events when not being used for actual typing. For example, I want various keys to trigger a manual click in the appropriate areas to reload, crouch, shoot, move, etc. in PUBG mobile.

In an active activity, I can capture a keyboard event as follows:

```
public class MainActivity implements KeyEvent.Callback {
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { ... }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { ... }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int count, KeyEvent event) { ... }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { ... }
}
```

I am unfamiliar with background operations on Android, but the developer page over viewing [background services](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service) explicitly states that:

> It can't interact directly with your user interface. To put its results in the UI, you have to send them to an Activity.
>
> Work requests run sequentially. If an operation is running in an IntentService, and you send it another request, the request waits until the first operation is finished.

Both these limitations prevent a background service from being a viable option for my keyboard trick, not to mention I have no clue how to capture keyboard events in these services.

What other options do I have?

Also, would I get banned from PUBG mobile for successfully setting up such a thing?